# Why does NFS hang after each file is copied?

Tags: networking, nfs

When I'm bulk copying files to my NAS over NFS, the file operation will hang for about 20 seconds after each file is copied.  Originally I thought is was just the POS consumer NAS box I was using with a RAID 5 array, but when I upgraded to a full blown file server using RAID 10, I noticed that it did exactly the same thing.  I tested the same operation via a Samba share and it didn't hang, so it doesn't seem to be network related. The actual file transfers saturate the Gb ethernet connection - it's just a long pause after each file.

Ubuntu 14.04

NFS is 1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.2

Relevant fstab line:

> 192.168.1.5:/mnt/shareroot /mnt/fileserver nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr

Any ideas?